# Rmarkdown beamer ignoring size option

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to create a presentation with Rmarkdown and beamer and I am unable to adjust the size of my code and output. In the past I edited the beamer template to work around this but I was hoping there is a better way.

For example:

````
---
title: "Reprex"
output:
  beamer_presentation
---

## Output one

```{r, size="footnotesize"}
1:50
```
````

renders identical to:

````
---
title: "Reprex"
output:
  beamer_presentation
---

## Output one

```{r}
1:50
```
````

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The `size` option specifies the "font size for the default LaTeX output" ([source](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/)). But you are writing rmarkdown which is converted to PDF afterwards.

A workaround:

````
---
output: beamer_presentation 
---

## Output one

Foo.

```{r, echo = FALSE}
knitr::asis_output("\\footnotesize")
1:10 # this will be small
knitr::asis_output("\\normalsize")
11:20 # this not
```

Bar.
````

Depending on how often this is used it could be work using a helper function or even a [chunk hook](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/) to print the font size commands.

Comment: Thanks for the response CL, but I'm not sure I understand your answer. Rmarkdown uses knitr and LaTeX as intermediates so setting the font size for the default LaTeX output should work. Also inserting raw LaTeX into the code chunk seems no better than reconfiguring the verbatim environment in the TeX templates.

Comment: @C.Hammill When you write a RMD document, `knitr` compiles it to MD (a markdown format). Thus, it cannot apply LaTeX font styles. This MD file is then converted to TEX/PDF via `pandoc`/`pdflatex`. The point is, you're not (directly) writing LaTeX, and therefore you should not expect the full flexibility of LaTeX - unless using hacky workarounds.